# Can i use multiple method type put on godaddy server?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing, godaddy-api

I Use two method type put in web-api.It is correct in localhost.but when i use this on godaddy server it is incorrect and i have error 405.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/MyController")]
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("Method1")]
  
    public returnObject Method1([FromBody]object1 object)
    {
        return  returnObject1
    }
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("Method2")]
    public returnObject2 Method2([FromBody]object2 object)
    {
       return  returnObject2
    }
}
```

---

But i dont access to applicationhost.config  in godaddy server however i try to add this section with this code in my project.

```
using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
            {
                Configuration configAdmin = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
                var section = configAdmin.GetSection("system.webServer/modules", "");
                var collection = section.GetCollection();
                var element = collection.CreateElement();
                element.Attributes["name"].Value = "ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0";
                element.Attributes["path"].Value = "*.";
                element.Attributes["verb"].Value = "GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG";
                element.Attributes["type"].Value = "System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler";
                element.Attributes["preCondition"].Value = "integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0";

                collection.Add(element);
                serverManager.CommitChanges();
            } 

                                                                                                                      when i run project and run up to line  element.Attributes["path"] this is null and i have error.
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem with the use of post method Instead of put method.
Thank you Ipsit Gaur

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure `PUT` verb is enabled on IIS on GoDaddy server by checking applicationhost.config file's line

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

And simply adding `PUT` verb there as it is disabled by default.

Comment: But i dont access to applicationhost.config  in godaddy server however i try add this with this code in my project.